# Nested generic type parameters

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, encapsulation

At the moment, I have a class:

```
ApiResponse<T> where T : IApiModel
```

Where this looks like:

```
ApiResponse<Contacts>
```

I'd like to modify the type constraint to have it look something like this instead:

```
ApiResponse<T1<T2>> where T1 : IApiModelCollection<T2> where T2 : IApiModel
```

And then call this like:

```
ApiResponse<Contacts<ContactDetails>>
```

How can i achieve this? The example above doesn't work unless I specify each type parameter separated by a `,` e.g:

```
ApiResponse<T1, T2>
```

Which would be called like this:

```
ApiResponse<Contacts, ContactDetails>
```

Is what I want to do possible? Or maybe there's a much better way?

Here's a sample class:

```
public class Contacts : IApiModelCollection<ContactDetails>
{
     // properties relevant to an api model collection
}

public class ContactDetails : IApiModel
{
    // etc...
}
```

And the interface looks like this:

```
IApiModelCollection<T> where T : IApiModel
```

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: You will need something like `ApiResponse<T1, T2> where (your existing where clauses)`.

Comment: What you want is impossible (I've been looking for that myself a few years back). Multiple type parameters must be separated by a comma in c#.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Ah I see - I'm not keen on `ApiResponse<Collection, CollectionItem>` but if there's no other way it will have to do

Comment: If you need to genericly know which type of element is in the collection, then yes, you need to do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your T for IApiModelCollection already in the interface so should'nt it be enough to do something like this?

```
ApiResponse<T> where T : IApiModelCollection<IApiModel>
```

Another Attempt I found would be a bit uglier:

```
ApiResponse<T1,T2> where T1 : IApiModelCollection<T2> where T2 IApiModel
```

Then you would have a call like:

```
ApiResponse<Contacts<ContactDetails>, ContactDetails>
```

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: This would not work if `T` ends up being (attempted) used as `IApiModelCollection<SomeConcreteTypeThatImplementsIApiModel>`.